# How to find the correlation coefficient

Tags: probability, expected-value, correlation

So we have these random variables A,B,C where A and B are 2 independent uniform distribution variables both with I=[$\frac {-1} {2}$,$\frac {1} {2}$]

$C=A+B$

We have to find the correlation coefficient $\rho_{AC}$

From what i know and have done so far $\rho_{AC}$=$\frac {\sigma_{AC}} {\sigma_A*\sigma_c}$

From what i did(hopefully i did it right):

Even though independent A and B basically have the same Variance
So $\sigma_{A}=\sigma_{B}=$$\frac {1} {12}$

What i dont know how to do is how to figure out the $\sigma_{AC}$

From what i know: $\sigma_{AC}=$E[AC]-$\mu_A\mu_C$

$\mu_A=0$ and $\mu_c=0$ since C=A+B and A and B are independent we can find $\mu_C=\mu_A+\mu_B$ and since $\mu_A=\mu_B=0$ $\mu_C=0$

So $\sigma_{AC}=E[AC]$

And this is where im stuck. I dont know how to calculate $E[AC]$

Comment: Hint AC = A(A+B)

Comment: @AndrewZhang -____- Hold up. You mean i can just multiply them there and get      $E[A^2 + AB]$ and then we have $E[A^2]+E[A]*A[B]$?

Comment: Yes you are correct